Can a single <span style>_____</span> be used to fomat all the paragraphs in an HTML document with several paragraphs
I have to enter HTML formatted info (sometimes it's several paragraphs) into a textbox on an online form used to create a webpage. I want to use a single <span style=> to format the entire entry at once.


<span style= "font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:14.0pt">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</span>



This works when I review it with my editor (Microsoft Front Page) but when posted on the webpage the font is not enlarged.
I've only gotten results using <span style> on individual paragraphs.

No. This is what divs are for. Spans are an inline tag, so that first <p> tag will cause the browser to end the span.

Also... Microsoft Front Page? The editor that hasn't had an update in twenty years? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage

Remove the space after = and you're missing a closing ".

@ceejayoz - No, that doesn't happen. The inline box created by the span element is broken around the block level box created by the p elements, but the span element wraps all three p elements just fine. Since named boxes inherit through the DOM tree, that means that the p elements inherit the font settings of the span element, and will display appropriately. None of which changes your essential point, which is that a div element is the correct element for the job.

Invalid HTML. Paragraphs can't be children of spans

Front Page is the very best WYSIWYG that I've ever used. You can type content in normal mode, view and edit the HTML that was created, and preview the finished web product easily. Please let me know of something else that does that.

@user3135388 Check out Quill Here's an example.

I may be confusing it with Microsoft FrontPage Express, but its main drawback used to be that once your site entered FrontPage it could not longer leave. It created its own mess of HTML tags that made it really hard to edit the resulting code with any other tool. It's fine if you're used to it and you like it, but it won't cope for anything invented in the last 20 years, and that's a lot of stuff.

You'll have to define a class.
When you put a . before the class name, it creates a custom class name that you can add to any tag with: class="span-style".
<html>
<head>
<style>
.span-style {
  font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><span class="span-style">1</span></p>
<p><span class="span-style">2</span></p>
<p><span class="span-style">3</span></p>
</body>
</html>

You have to wrap the <p>'s content with the span for each one.
You could also style the <p> or <span> directly:
<style>

/* Change the 'p' to 'span' and vice-versa */
/* Apply the same style block to both with a comma: 'p, span' */

p {
  font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
}
</style>

That will only work if that's the style you want for every <p>.
You could also remove the <span> use the <p> directly:
<p class="span-style">

I made this JSFiddle for reference with some extras.

CSS comments are /* */ not \\* *\\

Oh, yeah. Good call.

It appears that the proper coding is to use some textsome more text

You are correct in the classic sense of <details>/<summary>.  The <p> is not semantically considered by <section>.  In most non-textual cases, <div> is the go to tag, as it does not have any use expectations.
